# WORKDAY function - adding a specific time to a given date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using the Workday function to add 1 work day to a given date.

eg 12/09/2016 in A1 will automatically become 13/09/2016 in B1.

However, the date in column A and B is a custom format so it is actually 12/09/2016 9:00.

When I use the Workday function in B1 it becomes 13/09/2016 0:00 but i actually need it to be 09:00, not 0:00 on the next workday.

Also, when A1 is blank and doesn't contain a date, B1 automatically becomes 02/01/00 0:00 but i require it to stay blank if there is no data in A1.

Comment: It would help to show exactly how you're using the workday function

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand your questions however, I am using the workday function such that B1 =WORKDAY(A1,1) and the custom format in column B is dd/mm/yyyy h:mm. In my original post, I mistakenly wrote A2 when it should have been B1 (ie. a separate column).

Comment: That's all I meant - it wasn't clear if you were using it as part of some larger formula or just by itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't completely clear from your question where the cells in column A could be truly blank or simply a zero-length string returned by a formula in addition to being a true date. The [SUM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-function-0761ed42-45aa-4267-a9fc-a88a058c1a57) can evaluate a truly blank or zero-length string as numerically zero (e.g. FALSE).

```
=IF(SUM(A2), WORKDAY(A2, 1)+TIME(9, 0, 0), TEXT(,))
```

The [TIME function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TIME-function-9A5AFF99-8F7D-4611-845E-747D0B8D5457) can add nine hours to the result returned by the [WORKDAY function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WORKDAY-function-F764A5B7-05FC-4494-9486-60D494EFBF33).

[image: workday_time]

Answer (score 0):

To address the first part of your Q (display time) use in `A2`

```
=WORKDAY(A1,1)+J2-INT(A1)
```

To address the second part of your Q (suppress display when `A1` blank) use a custom format for `A2`

```
[>10]dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm;;;
```

<sub>Note: this format will hide the first week or so in 1900.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

For the second part, simply wrap the above with logic that says "If cell is blank, return a blank" like this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"", WORKDAY(INT(A1)))
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the this section at the beginning to stop blank cells in Column A showing 'False'.